# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'emit')

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

```
import { io } from "socket.io-client";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Game = () => {

  const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [room, setRoom] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    setSocket(io(process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL));

    return () => {
      socket.emit("disconnect");
    };
  }, [socket]);

  const sendMessage = () => {
    socket.emit("room1", { name, room });
    socket.off();
  };

  return (
    ...
  );
};

export default Game;
```

Hi all.As in the title I am getting this error.If i delete `socket` in useEffect dependency i dont get this error anymore but this time i get `React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'socket'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` error.

Comment: `socket` will be temporarily null, so a quick fix is to change `socket.emit("disconnect")` to `socket?.emit("disconnect")`.

Comment: If i do that  i get `Error: "disconnect" is a reserved event name`

Comment: Well that's a separate issue -- but it didn't throw a null pointer exception, which is what your post was about.  Check the docs for socket.io-client to resolve that second issue about "disconnect".

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to define socket, now it is just undefined.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const socket = io(process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL);
    setSocket(socket);

    return () => {
      socket.emit("disconnect");
    };
  }, [socket]);
```

And also you need to be careful with your function cause your send message function will have socket as undefined.

Edit: so I noticed that you are using states and you can change slightly to get it also working with states

```js
useEffect(() => {
    setSocket(await io(process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL));

    return () => {
      socket.emit("disconnect");
    };
  }, [socket]);
```

Edit 2: and you should await your socket connection

Comment: Tnx but it doesnt work.If i use async/await i get `Effect callbacks are synchronous to prevent race conditions  Put the async function inside ` and if i solve it as the error shows then my useEffect work multiple time and frozen.